# Laravel - Using image intervention in Jobs. Path error

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm trying to use image intervention in Jobs but it seems that the path is not correctly read. Meanwhile in a normal controller, it works.
There are the codes in my job:

```
$img = Image::make('storage/app/picture/1.jpg)->resize(1280, 720);
```

It outputs this error:

> Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotReadableException Image source
>   not readable

But it does work when put in normal controller instead of jobs.

Is there any way I can solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `path` method of `Storage` facade.

```
$img = Image::make(Storage::path('picture/1.jpg'))->resize(1280, 720);
```

Or `storage_path()` helper:

```
$img = Image::make(storage_path('app/picture/1.jpg'))->resize(1280, 720);
```

It witll return absolute path to file.

Comment: Thanks, done that. Now I'm getting this error: Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagettfbbox() but in normal controller there is no problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RedzwanLatif This problem is for another question.